# Add Swagger Basic AUTH to Spring Boot App

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger, springfox

Requirements:

- Spring Boot application with Springfox
- Add BASIC authentication to Swagger
- Pass on all other requests

Code: implemented

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/swagger-resources/*", "*.html", "/api/v1/swagger.json")
                .hasAuthority("SWAGGER")
                .anyRequest().permitAll()
            .and()
                .httpBasic()
            .and()
                .csrf().disable();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("admin").password("admin").authorities("SWAGGER");
    }
}
```

This code however does not work - you can freely browse /swagger-ui.html#/ without any authentcation.

Question is - why BASIC auth and user do not apply to swagger ui endpoint?

Comment: Of course it doesn't work, you're using `.permitAll()` instead of `.authenticated()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the `.authenticated()` instead of `.permitAll()`:

```
.authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/swagger-resources/*", "*.html", "/api/v1/swagger.json")
        .hasRole("SWAGGER")
    .anyRequest()
        .authenticated()
```

This will:

- Restrict access to all resources matching `/swagger-resources/*`, `*.html` and `/api/v1/swagger.json`
- Allow unauthenticated access to all other resources

For clarification on why your configuration doesn't work, it's because you're not reading spring-security like you should be reading it.

Your old configuration reads like this:

```
.authorizeRequests() // allow requests
    .antMatchers(...) // that matches this
        .hasAuthority("SWAGGER") // with SWAGGER authority
    .anyRequest() // All requests above
        .permitAll() // grant full access
```

In other words, you're granting full access to users with the `SWAGGER` authority, but what you've neglected is that by default, they already have access to it. To be more precise, ***everybody* has access to it unless you specify otherwise**.

By using `.authenticated()`. you're telling Spring that you want all requests matched to be restricted to people with the proper `role` or `authority`.

New configuration:

```
.authorizeRequests() // allow requests
    .antMatchers(...) // that matches this
        .hasRole("SWAGGER") // with role SWAGGER
    .anyRequest() // all requests above
        .authenticated() // needs authentication
```

### Update

Regarding your issue with `/swagger-resources`, `/swagger-resources/configuration/security` and `swagger-resources/configuration/ui` returning 401:

You should replace `/swagger-resources/*` for `/swagger-resources/**`.

### Update 2

Add the following at the **end** of your configuration to permit all non-matched requests:

```
.authorizeRequests()
    .anyRequest()
        .permitAll();
```

Comment: I've started getting "Unable to infer base url. This is common when using dynamic servlet registration or when the API is behind an API Gateway. The base url is the root of where all the swagger resources are served." in browser. It should be something with ant matcher?

Comment: In addition, authentication works BUT swagger UI does not render. When swagger-ui.html loads, it invokes js script, which does 3 requests /swagger-resources, /swagger-resources/configuration/security, swagger-resources/configuration/ui. All of them result in 401. They do have a matcher and do open in browser. Please help.

Comment: /swagger-resources/* is not the case of 401, i think it is a bug in js, which does not provide AUTHORIZATION header. I've rolled back to different version and the header is provided.

Comment: @Cortlendt are you sure? `/swagger-resources/*` should not match `/swagger-resources/configuration/security` and `/swagger-resources/configuration/security` whereas `/swagger-resources/**` should.

Comment: I'm using 2.2.6.1 version of springfox and it works. However, I have other problem - all other requests DO require basic auth now.

Comment: fixed by adding additional authorizeRequests fluent invocation in the end. .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();

Comment: @Cortlendt I updated my answer with that the moment you wrote that :P

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like below

### Swagger

The code for swagger is like below.

```java
    private List<SecurityScheme> basicScheme() {
        List<SecurityScheme> schemeList = new ArrayList<>();
        schemeList.add(new BasicAuth("basicAuth"));
        return schemeList;
    }

    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .
            .
            .
            .securitySchemes(basicScheme());
    }
```

### Security Config

For the security config

```java
    public void configureGlobal(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
        throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("USER")
                .password("PASSWORD")
                .roles("ADMIN");
    }
    .
    .
    .
    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
    .anyRequest().authenticated().and().sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and().httpBasic();
    }
    .
    .
    .
    @Override
    public void configure(final WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/v2/api-docs",
            "/configuration/ui",
            "/swagger-resources/**",
            "/webjars/**",
            "/configuration/security",
            "/swagger-ui.html");
    }
```

### Controllers

Below passes the authorization to the methods using swagger.

```java
   @PutMapping("/registration/{id}")
    @ApiOperation(value = "Update registration detail",
                  authorizations = { @Authorization(value="basicAuth") })
    public ResponseEntity<RegistrationModel> updateRegistration(
```

### POM

and in your pom.xml, you will be needing:

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

That's basically it.

Answer (score 1):

Your configuration is strange. You can try something like that:

```
public static void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable()
    .antMatcher("/swagger-ui.html")
    .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().hasAnyRole("SWAGGER")
        .and()
    .httpBasic();
}
```

This ensures authorization to `swagger-ui.html` path (with `SWAGGER` role).

Comment: really? In my case I use it specifically to a restricted page. Try add 
`security.basic.enabled=true` in your application.properties

Comment: What if you try to match by `"/swagger-ui*"`? I remember there were some issues with antMatchers and page extensions, since they evaluate against `servletPath` + `pathInfo` (see [AntPathRequestMatcher docs](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.1.2.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/util/matcher/AntPathRequestMatcher.html))